# Can I double every text line of a file using sed in linux bash?

Tags: bash, sed

Can I double every text line of a file using sed in linux bash?

Example file:

```
aab1
aac2
awq6a
azs4
```

What i want:

```
aab1 | aab1
aac2 | aac2
awq6a | awq6a
azs4 | azs4
```

I know about "read line" but yet,
how i am doing it:

- by only using sed command?
- by using "read line"?

ps. I want to double each line of the dir output command to use it for manipulation.

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: I have used sed, but i know that it can do process multiple lines for single string replace and not multiple lines with multiple string replace in same text. So i dont know. I think only read line can solve that with sed or awk --- put the $line at the end of each text line. so no attempt. But i asked if sed can do it that without invoking read line. so no idea.

Comment: Can you please add your Sed, and other, attempts to the question itself?

Comment: Homework task, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using read is very basic

```
while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%s | %s\n"  "$line" "$line" ; done < filename
```

sed is not any more complicated

```
sed -r 's/(.*)/\1 | \1/' filename
```

In general, it would be more helpful if you included what you've already tried so that we know that you're learning and so we don't duplicate your efforts.

Comment: +1 for the `sed` ;)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :)

Comment: Even simpler: `sed 's/.*/& | &/' filename`